# How can I add a picture inside a card in HTML?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Please bear with me as I am new in learning PHP. I am trying to make a registration form that will look exactly like this picture below:

[image]

And the one that I have made so far is this:

[image]

I have no idea how to add that picture on the left side. Here is my code:

```
<?php require_once 'indexheader.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leafnote | Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 m-auto">
        <div class="card bg-white mt-5">
          <div class="card-title text-black">
            <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold mb-0 mt-2">Register</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">      
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register" class="pt-3">Register</button>   

                  <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account? 
                    <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand...why you have to use php to insert an image? this image come from a db? why you don't use the _<img src="" alt="">_ tag?

Comment: Sorry, already edited the question. Also I have added that tag but the image will be shows above the card, not left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap grid to your card

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto">
      <div class="card bg-white mt-5 p-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 my-auto mx-auto"> <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" class="img-fluid"></div>
          <div class="col-8 mx-auto my-auto">
            <div class="card-title text-black">
              <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold mb-0 mt-2">Register</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2">
                <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2">
                <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2">
                <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register" class="pt-3">Register</button>

                <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account?
                  <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: flex;` available in bootstrap which gives more flexibility in aligning items in the center rather than using columns and adding extra css styles for alignment. Hope this sample code helps

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 m-auto">
      <div class="card d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center bg-white mt-5">

        <img class="mx-4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">

        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">

          <div class="card-title text-black align-self-baseline">
            <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold mb-0 mt-2">Register</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">

            <form action="process.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register" class="pt-3">Register</button>

              <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account?
                <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can add this picture inside the card?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is add another col(umn) next to your existing one.

That would look like this:

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img width='100%' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Nicolas_Cage_Deauville_2013.jpg'/>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card bg-white mt-5">
          <div class="card-title text-black">
            <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold mb-0 mt-2">Register</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">      
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register" class="pt-3">Register</button>   
                  <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account? 
                    <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You might need to play a bit with the CSS to make your image look good.
Have a look at the doc for details on the Bootstrap grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want the image inside the card.

Comment: And do you want it on top of it (like you said in your latest comment) or left?

Comment: On the left like the first picture of my OP

Comment: Ok. In that case, it seems you can't do it natively with the Bootstrap  Card component (see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#images-1)). You could still try to add the picture *inside* the `<div class="card">` but you'll probably have issues making your CSS work. In the end, I'd stick with my proposal :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need bootstrap card code with left aling image.

```
<div class="container-fluid">  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto">
           <div class="card flex-row flex-wrap">
                <div class="card-header border-0">
                    <img src="https://www.placehold.it/200" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="card-block px-2">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Description</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</a>
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="card-footer w-100 text-muted">
                    Footer stating cats are CUTE little animals
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 m-auto">
        <div class="card bg-white mt-5">
          <div class="card-title text-black">
            <h5 class="text-center py-2 font-weight-bold mb-0 mt-2">Register</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
              <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="passw" placeholder="Password" class="form-control mb-2"> 
                  <input type="text" name="passw2" placeholder="Re-enter password" class="form-control mb-2">      
                  <button class="btn btn-success btn-block mt-3" name="register">Register</button>   

                  <div class="text-center mt-3" style="font-size: 14px;">Already have an account? 
                    <a href="signup.php" class="alert-link">Login</a>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]